# Confused about passing arguments from command line (optparse) R, arguments not getting stored even with explicit 'default' option

Tags: r

Learning how to use R from the command line. I've come across the 'optparse' package and started using it. Thought everything was fine til I noticed it was not behaving as I initially expected, and couldn't make it write a file in the directory I wanted.

In order to keep things simple, I decided to use a short script to explain what's going on:

```
require(optparse)

#Parse arguments from command line
options <- list(
  make_option(c("-d", "--directory"), action = "store", default = getwd(), type = "character", help="Working directory path."),
  make_option(c("-e", "--extension"), action = "store", default = ".tsv", type = "character", help="File(s) extension."),
  make_option(c("-p", "--outputPath"), action = "store", default = getwd(), type = "character", help="Output file(s) directory to be saved at."),
  make_option(c("-o", "--outputName"), action = "store", default = "output", type = "character", help="Output file(s) base name."),
  make_option(c("-s", "--separator"), action = "store", default = NA, help="Separator to use explicitely")
)
arguments <- parse_args(OptionParser(option_list = options))

setwd(arguments$d) 

cat(arguments$d, arguments$e, arguments$s)
```

This works fine, it shows:

```
C:/Users/path/to/where/I/work .tsv NA
```

However, asking for the 'outputPath' and outputName' arguments

```
cat(arguments$p, arguments$o)
```

prints absolutely nothing... even though I explicitely gave those arguments a default value, a type, and an action. The outputPath option is literally the same thing as the directory option!

Using getwd(), as.character(getwd()), or even as.character(file.path(getwd())) gives the same result for the option 'outputPath'.

Passing the arguments from the command line (instead of using the default values) returns the exact same thing (what you'd expect for arguments$d, arguments$e, arguments$s, and nothing for arguments$p, arguments$o)

I am super confused about that; and of course, when trying to work with those variables in my real script... well it's impossible, cause it says that they have length zero...

Interestingly, if I do:

```
cat(unlist(arguments))
```

I do get the output I would expect... but I also get an additional logical variable with value FALSE, at the end of my argument list. I don't know where that came from...

```
C:/Users/path/to/where/I/work .tsv C:/Users/path/to/where/I/work output NA FALSE
```

I run this on the Windows powershell as:

```
Rscript.exe .\script.R
```

When I type the long flag (ex. --outputName something), the flag 'lights' and turns white on the terminal, whereas using the short one (ex. -o something) does not (it looks greyish on the command line, as if it is unused or something). Don't know if it means anything, since both do the exact same thing. Just wanted to point it out.

One last thing! Of course 'C:/Users/path/to/where/I/work' is not the real directory path, and the one I'm actually using has a whitespace on it... do you think that matters?

EDIT: Ok now I know where that FALSE came from, just needed to print my 'arguments' list... I feel dumb. But still, the original problem persists... and it confuses me more now, cause the values ARE stored in my 'argumens' list.

Doing:

```
arguments
```

Shows:

```
$directory
[1] "C:/Users/alang/Desktop/LabiVicenteLau D="

$extension
[1] ".tsv"

$outputPath
[1] "C:/Users/alang/Desktop/LabiVicenteLau D="

$output
[1] "output"

$separator
[1] NA

$help
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partial matching of arguments is your (I guess not) friend.

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
require(optparse)

#Parse arguments from command line
options <- list(
  make_option(c("-d", "--directory"), action = "store", default = getwd(), type = "character", help="Working directory path."),
  make_option(c("-e", "--extension"), action = "store", default = ".tsv", type = "character", help="File(s) extension."),
  make_option(c("-p", "--outputPath"), action = "store", default = getwd(), type = "character", help="Output file(s) directory to be saved at."),
  make_option(c("-o", "--outputName"), action = "store", default = "output", type = "character", help="Output file(s) base name."),
  make_option(c("-s", "--separator"), action = "store", default = NA, help="Separator to use explicitely")
)
arguments <- parse_args(OptionParser(option_list = options))

setwd(arguments$d)

print("R tries to match anything starting with an o.")
print(arguments$o)
print("No success")
print("R tries not to partially matchi anything. Explicitly call argument.")
print(arguments$outputPath)
print("Great success!")
```

The above script gives me:

```
romunov@kista  ~/Documents
$ ./test.R
Loading required package: optparse
Warning message:
package 'optparse' was built under R version 3.5.3
[1] "R tries to match anything starting with an o."
NULL
[1] "No success"
[1] "R tries not to partially matchi anything. Explicitly call argument."
[1] "C:/Users/romunov/Documents"
[1] "Great success!"
```

Comment: Yup, just figured it out :D thanks! I think there might be a way to make it work the way I tried to match initially, but right now I'll do it this way.

Comment: You should match arguments by their full name. Your code should be readable, not short.